# Text Vectorization with tensors containing multiple columns (labels)

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am working on a multi-label classification problem and I am trying to run this code from another source:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
max_length = 600
max_tokens = 20000
text_vectorization = layers.TextVectorization(
max_tokens=max_tokens,
output_mode="int",
output_sequence_length=max_length,
)
text_vectorization.adapt(text_only_train_ds)
int_train_ds = train_ds.map(
lambda x, y: (text_vectorization(x), y)),
num_parallel_calls=4)  #I am having issues with this part
```

My data looks like this:

```
Txt          | Politics | Religion | Fun  
lets go play | 0        |0         |1  
I dont know  | 0        |0         |0
```

I tried this:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
max_length = 600
max_tokens = 20000
text_vectorization = layers.TextVectorization(
max_tokens=max_tokens,
output_mode="int",
output_sequence_length=max_length,
)
text_vectorization.adapt(text_only_train_ds) 




batch_size=200000
def df_to_dataset(dataframe,categories, shuffle=True):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe[categories]
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds  
train_ds = df_to_dataset(df_train,categories)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(df_val,categories, shuffle=False)  

int_train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda d: (text_vectorization(d['txt']), d['Politics'],d['Religion'],d['Fun']))
```

I get this error:

> lambda() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

How do I get to run text_vectorization on the text column by parsing through a tensor?

Comment: What does `text_only_train_ds` look like?